# excel conditional formatting multiple functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic table with for example 5 columns:

- **1st column** -> only has "AA" or "BB" strings.
- **2nd/5th column** -> only has one letter values.

I already have rules that:

- If a line has **AA** in the 1st column, it fills the line with color yellow.
- If a line has **BB** in the 1st column, it fills the line with color blue.

I use this formula, and it works:

```
=Search("AA"; $A1)>0
```

Now I want a rule that:

- If I find the letter **M** in the other columns, but it's on the **AA** line, the cell with **M** it's filled with other color, let's say green.
- If I find the letter **M** in the other columns, but it's on the **BB** line, the cell with **M** it's filled with another color, let's say red.

Is this possible?

EDIT:
The figure below represents what I want:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ALAe.png)

Comment: I would much rather create a helper column that you have your if conditions in and outputs "blue", "green", "red" etc. and have the conditional formatting look at that column instead. Conditional formatting and multiple conditions is very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search wont find things easily across cells.

It is better to use another function. I typically use `COUNTIF` in this case.

Highlight only one cell in your table and use this as the formula in the conditional formatting.
This one gives your the highlight on the cell with "M" only:

`=AND(SEARCH("AA", $A1)>0, A1="M")`

`=AND(SEARCH("BB", $A1)>0, A1="M")`

For the row use this:

`=COUNTIF($A1,"AA")>0`

`=COUNTIF($A1,"BB")>0`

After putting the conditional formatting in only one cell, change the "Applies to" field to reflect the whole range you wish apply it to. This relies on relative references in conditional formatting. This can get very messy very quickly, so I recommend manually editing the "Applies to" field instead of copy/paste formats to the specified areas.
[image]

Edit: Updated the picture and formulas to reflect the update to the question's clarity.

Comment: This way all the line is being filled with a color right? In your example, the first line should had **AA has yellow**; A,C and B nothing; and **M with green**.

Comment: @Enorio The formula will highlight what you want. The ranges they are applied to can be modified as you please. The original question didn't clearly differentiate between what needs to be colored and when.

Comment: I've edited the question with an image. And this formula it's not filling the cells with the respective color. The CountIf should not be in all column except the first one?

Comment: @Enorio I have updated the answer for you. All formulas go into the conditional formatting for the whole table.

Comment: I changed the A1="M" to B2="M" and now it works, because with A1 to me was shifting right the fill.

Answer (score 1):

By other columns, I assume you mean if any other column in your table has the string `M`

```
=AND(Search("AA"; $A1) > 0; OR($B1 = "M"; $C1 = "M"; $D1 = "M"; $E1 = "M"))
```

Comment: Nice, it's working. But is there a better way to do this? My real example has 31 columns, and I didn't want to put all the columns in the OR

Comment: @Enorio helper column would be my other route then

Comment: Or look at Davids solution

Answer (score 0):

The two set of formulas are to be:

If I find the letter M in the other columns, but it's on the AA line, it's filled with other color, let's say green.

```
=AND(SEARCH("AA",$A2)>0,OR($B2="M",$E2="M"))
```

If I find the letter M in the other columns, but it's on the BB line, it's filled with another color, let's say red.

```
=AND(SEARCH("BB",$A2)>0,OR($B2="M",$E2="M"))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain very well, but the red and green fill should go to the other columns. But yes, this formula works