# conditonally format cell in column A based on Criteria in other Columns

Tags: excel

I have a report where `columns BT:DB` have `0's` and `1's`. If there is a `1` in that row for an employee, I'd like to highlight the employee's name in `column A`. I do not want to highlight the whole row.

How would I enter a conditional formatting formula to say: If a cell in this row has a `1` in `columns BT:DB`, then highlight those cells with `1's` and also the employee name in `column A` of that row, as well?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601869/excel-conditional-formatting-multiple-functions/) may help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to apply your conditional format to `Column A`.

> Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Then use the formula: `=SUM(BT1:DB1)` (No locked cell references on row)

`0 = False` & `>0 = True` which will decide if your column is highlighted or not. You can also choose what range to apply the format to.

---

I used different ranges below so I can fit the example nicely into a screen shot. You will just need to update the ranges to fit your specific needs.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this without adding a formula (column) to the data?

Comment: @BigBen heroes <3

Comment: @nicklanta there's no formula column added to the data, the conditional formatting uses a formula. Or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: @urdearboy it worked for the names in column A, but it doesn't highlight the cells with 1 in the aforementioned range. Is there another piece I need to add to get that second bit?

Comment: @nicklanta use a separate rule for that.

Comment: @urdearboy thanks, again. Sorry if I made any of this confusing, appreciate the help

Comment: @urdearboy sorry, last thing, but is there a way to have it apply for everything but the first two rows (headers)? it's highlighting them as well

Comment: Oh my screen shot, update the first table that says “Applies to”. Remove any ranges you don’t want this rule to apply to.

Comment: @urdearboy I think it's not working because I didn't add these `0=false & 1=true` conditions, where do I plug that in?

its just highlighting random people in column A, regardless whether or not they have a 1 or 0

Comment: You don’t add those conditions. That is how conditional formats interpret 0s and 1s. It’s the default

Comment: @urdearboy, if I wanted to point out people with a sum of 3 or more, would I just add this: `=SUM(BT1:DB1)>3`?

Comment: `>=` if you want 3 or more.

Comment: If you want this to be 3 or more you need >2.